# Color background or text in angular bootstrap-ui accordion based on value

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am following this example, accordion example in  http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap but I just want the header to be in red or background in red depending on a value. I can't get the heading to be red based on value or have a simple `background-color`. Inner div works with `ng-class`.

This is the data (SV)

```
[
    {"Goal":"X","Task":"A","TaskArgument":null},
    {"Goal":"X","Task":"B","TaskArgument":null},
    {"Goal":"X","Task":"B","TaskArgument":null},
]

[
    {"Goal":"Y","Task":"A","TaskArgument":null},
]
```

in HTML

```
<accordion>
    <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in SV" >
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <accordion-group heading="{{value[0].Goal}}" ng-class="{red:value[0].Goal=='X'}">
                <div ng-repeat="v in value">
                    <div ng-class="{red: v.Task=='B'}">{{v.Task}}</div>
                </div>
            </accordion-group>
        </div>
    </div>
</accordion>
```

Comment: Please include as much relevant css and javascript as possible... Your question is not specific enough.

Comment: Ok. I gave accordion example in http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap as the basis of the question.